# Geometry in python and jupyter notebook with link to spatial analyses

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am a confused by the number of libraries. I tested triangle and sympy but wasn't satisfied.

I want to make a lecture script for students and visualize some geometry primitives (Point, Line, Polygon). Therefore I want to demonstrate some analyses.

Triangulation - seems to work with Triangle. But how to demonstrate distances e.g. centroid to centroid, nearest neighbour. It would be fine to draw a line where the measurements go through between the shapes.

I also wants to demonstrate some analysis like point in polygon but get confused by visualizing.

Are there any recommendations for libraries, examples and tutorials at best as jupyter notebook.

Comment: [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) (GEOS bindings) is probably one of the most common python library to manipulate planar geometry primitives and compute basic predicate operation (within, overlaps, interects, etc.). See it's documentation : https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. You may also find some methods usable in spatial analysis in packages such as [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) (Delaunay triangulation, etc.). I won't go into details here but [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) will do the job for visualizing, there is a few resources about geospatial python out there.

Answer (score 1):

A good online course `**Introduction to Python GIS -course 2018**` is available [here](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/index.html). All the resources:- lectures, exercises, programs and etc, can be found there.

For your specific needs on `geometry` objects and theirs related topics, you can find them [here](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L1/Geometric-Objects.html).

In the `software installation` section [here](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/course-info/Installing_Anacondas_GIS.html)  you will see all the recommmended libraries / packages they use in the course. Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the realy usefull links. The Course is very good. I'm obviously a beginner in python, forgive me.  I want to show my students some similiar but I want to visualize it more. How could I display the coordinate systems, the shapes (point, line, polygon) and the analyses e.g. the distances? I would do that in a jupyter notebook. Is shapely well supportet there?

Comment: @Torsten  I have made a program to demo some spatial operations here:
http://swatchai.pythonanywhere.com/geo/default/spatial_overlay_processing  -- with visualization.

Comment: @Torsten If you are able to set nodeJS/ijavascript kernel to serve your Jupyter notebook, I recommnend installing and use `turf` http://turfjs.org/docs/.

Comment: Thanks for the link to turf. In the beginning I will concentrate on shapely. But I am confused by visualisation. With p1=Point(2,2) I can create a point and with "p1" the Point is to see. How cann I show the Point inside a plot with coordinates?